# Validate a date up to current time

Tags: c

i'm doing a program in c that needs to have random dates that have to be valid and after the current date. For the generation there aren't any problems at all. The only thing i can't do is to accept only the up to date dates.

I've already tried to firstly check if the date is valid and then to check if is greater than current date. Then i've tried to do the opposite but any of these solutions didn't worked.

This is the function that checks the date:

```
short dateControl( const unsigned short day, const unsigned short month, const unsigned short year, const int min_year, const int max_year, struct tm curTime)
{
    short correct = ZERO;

    if( (year >= curTime.tm_year) && (year <= max_year) ){
        if( (month >= 1) && (month <= 12) ){
            if( (day >= 1 && day <= 31) && (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) ){
                correct = ONE;
            }else if( (day >= 1 && day <= 30) && (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) ){
                correct = ONE;
            }else if( (day >= 1 && day <= 28) && (month == 2) ){
                correct = ONE;
            }else if( day == 29 && month == 2 && (year % 400 == 0 ||(year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)) ){
                correct = ONE;
            }else{
                correct = ZERO;     
            }
        } else{
            correct = ZERO;         
            }
    }else{
        correct = ZERO;             
    }

if(correct == ONE){
    if( year > curTime.tm_year ){
            correct = ONE;
        }else if( year == curTime.tm_year ){
            if( month > curTime.tm_mon ){
                correct = ONE;
            }else if( month == curTime.tm_mon ){
                if( day > curTime.tm_mday ){
                    correct = ONE;
                }else if(day == curTime.tm_mday){
                    correct = ZERO;
                }else if(day < curTime.tm_mday){
                    correct = ZERO;
                }
            }else if( month < curTime.tm_mon ){
                correct = ZERO;
            }
        }
    }
}

    return correct;
}
```

This is the part where the date is generated

```
day = random_int(1, 31);
month = random_int(1, 12);
year = random_int(local->tm_year, local->tm_year + 1);
validDate = dateControl(tempTrip.dep_date.day, tempTrip.dep_date.month, tempTrip.dep_date.year, local->tm_year, (local->tm_year + 1), *local);
    while(validDate == ZERO){
    tempDriver.sub_date.day = random_int(1, 31);
    tempDriver.sub_date.month = random_int(1, 12);
    tempDriver.sub_date.year = random_int(local->tm_year, (local->tm_year + 1));
    validDate = dateControl(tempTrip.dep_date.day, tempTrip.dep_date.month, tempTrip.dep_date.year, local->tm_year, (local->tm_year + 1), *local);
    }
    }
```

I expect that if the generated date is 2/7/2019 and today is the 18/8/2019, the generated date needs to be discarded and another needs to be generated.

Comment: The generally-accepted easy'n'correct way of doing date arithmetic and comparisons -- which would also apply to your problem of generating random dates -- is to do most/all of your work using `time_t` values, then convert to y/m/d at the very end.

Comment: In your existing code, part of your problem may be that `tm_mon` goes from 0 to 30, not 1 to 31.  Also `tm_year` does not contain a full 4-digit year; it's actually y-1900.

Comment: I would just do `time_t mintime = time(NULL); time_t maxtime = mintime + 365 * 86400; time_t randtime = random_int(mintime, maxtime); struct tm *rand_tm = localtime(&randtime);`.

Comment: @SteveSummit thanks for the support. For the tm_mon and the tm_year i already added 1 and 1900 but i forgot to put these lines in the answer, sorry.

Comment: Side point: If the code in front of you doesn't match the code here, that makes things particularly difficult for us.  Please make sure to copy and paste your code exactly!

Comment: it is the same. Only that when i declared the time struct, i added 1 and 1900 for the month and the year

Comment: Oh, and my bad: you figured this out, but what I meant to say was that `tm_mon` goes from 0 to 11, not 1 to 12.

Comment: **Never ever** do date "arithmetic" yourself. [The Daily WFT](http://www.thedailywtf.com/) is full of reports about errors with self built functions. Look for a library that provides the functions you need, and you're done.

Comment: @thebusybee can you tell me a library that does this please?

Comment: The busybee is right, but in this case you don't need such a library if you follow my suggestion about `randtime` above.

Comment: @SteveSummit i will try these suggestions.

Comment: You probably need to abandon your existing `dateControl` function and start over, but a few additional points: (1) Don't do `#define ONE 1` and `#define ZERO 0`.  Do `#define TRUE 1` and `#define FALSE 0`. (2) Why pass in `min_year` if you're going to compare against `curTime.tm_year`?

Comment: @SteveSummit because the function firstly checks if the date is valid as a date and then checks if is greater than current date

Comment: @Handysaur You might already have found a library to use if you follow @SteveSummit's suggestion (even if the range can be smaller than a full year.) It is the standard C library. Oh, and please don't define boolean constants yourself. Put `#include <stdbool.h>` in your source and use `bool`, `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 1):

> i'm doing a program in c that needs to have random dates that have to be valid and after the current date. For the generation there aren't any problems at all. The only thing i can't do is to accept only the up to date dates.

The fact that you need to determine if the date is/isn't valid indicates that the way you're generating random dates is a problem.

Specifically, if you get the current time (using `time()`) and add a random positive value to it (while being careful to avoid overflow), and then convert the result into a date (e.g. using `gmtime()`); then you can guarantee that the random dates are valid and in the future without doing any checking and you can delete all of your `dateControl()` code.